# measure from scratch

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

So I am doing some basic measure theory, namely the exterior measure. Given a subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}$ we denote its exterior measure by

$m_*(E) = \inf \Sigma_{j=1}^\infty \vert Q_j \vert$ where the infimum is taken over all countable coverings of $E$ by closed cubes.

First must show $m_*(\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]) =0$

So this is basically all rationals between $0$ and $1$ and including $0$ and $1$. So basically measure of a bunch of singletons? How can I show this? Here is my attempt

$m_*(\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]) = \inf \Sigma_{j=1}^\infty \vert Q_j \vert$ where $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty Q_j$ then what would my $Q_j$ be? I know points are like cubes of volume $0$ but how do I make this more rigorous?

Similarly how can I show $m_*([0,1]) = 1$?

Could I take the cube to be $[0,1]$ and its just one single $Q_j$? say $Q_1 = [0,1]$ which has volume 1 and the closed unit interval is a subset of itself clearly so?

Comment: One of the rules of measures is that $$m_*\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right)=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^\infty m_*(A_i)$$It's pretty easy to see why that implies all countable sets have measure $0$, given that singleton sets do. Also, $[0,1]$ is a closed unit interval, so we usually define it to have measure $1$ by construction. You might be using different definitions, though. Check em out.

Comment: do you mean countable SUB additivity?? I thought exterior measure only has sub additive. Definitely using different definitions. I have seen these more of immediate consequences in certain texts but require some work to show in others